# Triggers PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Tengo el siguiente trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_insercion_evento 
AFTER INSERT ON evento
BEGIN
INSERT INTO historico_evento(historico_evento.id, historico_evento.fecha_cambio, historico_evento.evento_id, historico_evento.usuario_exowner)
VALUES(NULL, sysdate, :NEW.id, :NEW.usuario_owner)
END tr_insercion_evento;//
```

En PhpMyAdmin indico que el delimitador es "//" (también intenté realizarlo desde la sentencia misma con "DELIMITER //", pero no hay caso:

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'TRIGGER tr_insercion_evento 
AFTER INSERT ON evento
BEGIN
INSERT ' en la linea 1
```

### Tabla evento

id (int pk), titulo(text),  inicio(date), final(date), usuario_owner(int fk->usuario)

### Tabla historico_evento

id (int pk), fecha_cambio(date), evento_id(int fk->evento), usuario_exowner(int)

### Tabla usuario

id(int pk), nombre(text)

Nota: Por si acaso, aclaro que las restricciones que di a las fk son en cascada (update y delete).

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Por lo que he leído en foros y aquí mismo, muchos tenemos problemas con phpmyadmin. En Workbench podría realizarlo, pero quisiera saber como solucionar este inconveniente desde phpmyadmin mismo. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es el delimitador. El problema (principal) es que estás usando la sintaxis de Oracle para definir el trigger, no la sintaxis de MySQL (`OR REPLACE`, `:NEW`, `sysdate` sin paréntesis, etc.).

En MySQL el trigger sería:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_insercion_evento 
AFTER INSERT ON evento FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO historico_evento(id, fecha_cambio, evento_id, usuario_exowner)
  VALUES(NULL, sysdate(), NEW.id, NEW.usuario_owner);
END;//
```

Y de ser necesario, le agregas las sentencias `DELIMITER` antes y después de la definición del trigger.

Comment: Buenísimo, la verdad que ni me di cuenta u.u. ¡Muchas gracias!